# Copy one table on sheet data to another table on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

**disclaimer** I have never used VBA before...

I have the following:
Sheet1 contains Table1
Sheet2 contains Table2

I want to copy content of Table1 and insert it into Table2.
Would you use a copy / paste method or use ListRows.add?

Here is how I can select the rows from Table1:

```
 ' Copy from src table
Set srcRows = srcSh.ListObjects("Table1")
srcRows.Parent.Activate
srcRows.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
srcRows.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

But then I am not sure how I can copy it at the end of the other table?

Another way I think of selecting the data would be to save content of the rows to a variable and then add it the destination table (but how?)

```
from = srcRows.DataBodyRange.Value
```

I saw the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrows.add#example add function but I am not sure how I would apply this selection to it.

Finally another simplified version I tried with a demo starting with the following:
[image]

My goal is to copy the rows from the second table to append them on the first one.

So I tried the following macro:

```
    Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3")
    Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")

  For x = 2 To tbl2.Range.Rows.Count
        tbl1.ListRows.Add.Range() = tbl2.Range.Rows(x).Value
  Next x
```

which would create the following result:
[image]

It is almost there but how can I make it to "paste" the values while starting on the foo column?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Use the macro recorder to record your actions click by click. Then work on the code provided by the recorder.

Comment: I would suggest using **Power Query** instead of VBA, please see this example [Combine data from multiple data sources (Power Query)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-data-from-multiple-data-sources-power-query-70cfe661-5a2a-4d9d-a4fe-586cc7878c7d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same issue, here is how I solved it using VBA:

```
Sub MacroYeah()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Source, Destination As ListObject
Dim r As Range
Dim index As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set Source = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")
    Set Destination = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3")

    Source.Parent.Activate
    Source.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Source.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    Set r = Destination.Range()
    r.Activate

    index = r.Rows.Count
    ActiveCell.Offset(index, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

It will copy the content of the 2nd table at the end of the first table while offsetting 1 row.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]